# Email2Case and Preventing an Email Domain from creating new Cases

Tags: email2case

I'm trying to determine if there is a way to prevent cases from being created from Email2Case if the origination email address comes from a certain domain.  So for example, if I'm talking about the domain hotmail.com, I want to create a trigger that prevents a new case from being created by Email2Case.

Would I need to create a new field that "finds" the domain portion of the email address?  I thought there might be a way to do a "like" or "contains" but I can't find any logic that supports either of those.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you guys might have!

Comment: Trigger or validation rule could both work, as far as I can tell. Are you using the OOTB email to case, or your own handler?

Comment: why not Validation Rule: `CONTAINS(LOWER(SuppliedEmail),'@hotmail.com')` ?  Email2Case sets Case.suppliedEmail; Validation Rules wil prevent the Case from being inserted - although it is a blunt instrument here - no hotmail.com case will ever be accepted

Comment: We're using the default Email2Case that comes with Salesforce.  I added your suggested validation rule, crop1645.  Thank you both for your help!